# Java: How do I get a unique serial ID for the computer that will never change

Tags: java, linux, windows, macos

I am making a program that requires a unique serial ID for the computer that is running the program. It needs to never change (or change very rarely AND the user has to know when it will change in advance). Also I need it to either work on Linux, Mac and Windows (maybe even Solaris) or one way for each.
I have tried this...

```
try
{
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]
    {
    "wmic", "bios", "get", "serialnumber"
    });
    process.getOutputStream().close();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(process.getInputStream());
    String property = sc.next();
    String serial = sc.next();
    System.out.println(property + ": " + serial);
} catch(IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but WMIC is only on windows. But other than that, it's perfect.
Just a way to do that on a Mac and in Linux would be perfect

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: voting, so you can't vote more than once on a computer

Comment: Suppose this were possible (which I'm not sure it is). What prevents someone from giving your program a fake ID?

Comment: A computer is not the unit you are looking for here

Comment: Heavy obfuscation, anything like a mac address or an IP changes often and a mac address can be changed any time you change your network adapter, some people use a usb one and can do so very often

Comment: Someone could, for example, create 10 virtual machines and run your program in each one. Then delete them, create another 10, run your program in each of those. And so on.

Comment: If you just want "a number that's as unique as possible", there are probably ways to do that... but if you need to *prevent people from changing their number*, then that's extremely difficult, probably impossible.

Comment: hard enough to change that you cant just change it in a few seconds, but a computer serial ID would work great

Comment: (Probably) no matter what you do, someone will make a tool that allows anyone to change their ID in a few seconds - whether it works by running your program in a VM, or modifying your program to replace the ID check with a random number generator, or something else.

Comment: i was hoping for something that is already in the computer in hardware, but how to access it

Comment: Computer voting is a hard problem, there is no known solution.  See for example https://freedom-to-tinker.com/blog/teaguehalderman/ivote-vulnerability/ and https://www.verifiedvoting.org/projects/internet-voting-statement/

Answer (score 1):

There is no computer serial number, even if there were, the client's software could be modified to send any number. You could somehow incorporate the network card's media access control address (MAC address), but that can be altered by software, or the card could be swapped out, or there could be multiple cards.

About the only thing you can do for a voting application is to use secure hardware that contains a unique number that can't be copied coupled with encryption. This is what smartcards do.

Comment: What about something like the hard drive serial ID or the motherboard, i was able to get a BIOS ID with my windows PC

Comment: @stealth9799 They can be faked. Almost everything you can think of can be faked. How much does security matter in this program?

Comment: not all so terribly much, but it should be a pain to have to do it enough times that it would matter in voting, like five, ten times doesnt matter